# limiting the input data on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, input

There is any function limiting the input data on codeigniter?

**Example:** 

User input qty '3'. 

Then, he took input for that 3 stuff. He can't input more than 3

i tried this so far. just for input that qty

```
public function ajax_add()
{
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
            'nama_produk' => $this->input->post('nama_produk'),
            'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
            'tanggal' => $this->input->post('tanggal'),
        );
    $insert = $this->barangmasuk->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: show here what you tried so far ?

Comment: Did you try codeigniter form validation library ?

Comment: @jothi done. i just try input qty

Comment: @SankarV im not understand validation library that you mean. its not limiting char

Comment: @kamenrider - check this - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html  .

Comment: @SankarV as i said before. its not like validation. my limiting data its dynamic. so if user, input 2 qty. then he must input only 2 stuff qty. im combine this for barcode, so there's not just small quantity, it can be a hundred. and then user just scan barcode 1 by 1 with quantity demanded.

Comment: In your question, you've added just 4 lines of code. `validate()` - do you want us to guess the function code? Do you think the other 3 lines will give anything to help you? "so if user, input 2 qty. then he must input only 2 stuff qty" - Here you've repeated the same 'input 2 qty' twice. It's not yet clear for me. I think you need to limit the Number of products with the number entered in the Quantity (please use full forms) field. In that case, you just need to check the number of elements in products array.